# User defined function returns #value! but then solves

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, user-defined-functions

I'm running the following code as a custom function:

```
Option Explicit

Function TextColon(Num1 As String) As String
    TextColon = Trim(Mid(Num1, InStr(1, Num1, ":") + 2))
End Function

Function Flatness(ByVal Num1 As String) As String
    Dim CellAddress As String
    CellAddress = ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Value
    Flatness = Trim(Mid(CellAddress, InStr(1, CellAddress, "DV=") + 3, InStr(1, CellAddress, "TO=") - InStr(1, CellAddress, "DV=") - 3))
End Function

Function Diameter(ByVal Num1 As String) As String
    Diameter = Trim(Mid(Num1, InStr(1, Num1, "AV=") + 3, InStr(1, Num1, "NV=") - InStr(1, Num1, "AV=") - 3))
End Function

Sub OptimizeVBA(isOn As Boolean)
    Application.Calculation = IIf(isOn, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
    Application.EnableEvents = Not (isOn)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Not (isOn)
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = Not (isOn)
End Sub

Function CMM(ByVal Num1 As String) As String
    Dim Output As String
    Dim CaseType As String
    
    OptimizeVBA True
    
    CaseType = Trim(Left(Num1, 18))
        
    Select Case CaseType
    Case "PART NUMBER", "REV", "OPERATION", "INSP / SN#", "DATE / TIME"
        Output = TextColon(Num1)
    Case "Diameter", "Position X", "Position Y", "Position Z", "Distance X", "Distance Y", "Distance Z", "Cone ang."
        Output = Diameter(Num1)
    Case "Flatness", "Perpendicularity", "Concentricity"
        Output = Flatness(Num1)
    Case Else
        Output = "No Value"
    End Select
    
    CMM = Output
    
    OptimizeVBA False
End Function
```

I'm having a problem with the Flatness function. I type =cmm(A1) in B1 and it solves correctly. Then I copy down to B100 and B2 to B100 show #value!. If I click on cell B2, then in the formula bar, then hit enter, cell B2 will evaluate correctly and the #value! disappears. Very strange, please help.

Also, any ideas for optimizing the code are appreciated as I'm a novice.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't rely on `ActiveCell`, instead add another parameter to your function and pass the offset cell.

Comment: I'm not sure but sometimes the Manual Calculations can screw with things like this. Try disabling the `OptimizeVBA` sub and try it again.

Comment: Instead of `ActiveCell` if you do need to reference some other cell relative to the cell with the formula, then in a UDF you can use `Application.Caller` or `Application.ThisCell` to get the calling cell.   +1 for removing the `OptimizeVBA` from the picture.

Comment: ...also by passing in `ByVal Num1 As String` to `CMM` you can't reference cells relative to  the source of `Num1` - if you pass that in `As Range` then you can offset from that to get relative cells...